# Filter values in select fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using Laravel 7 + Backpack CRUD 4.1.

I have two models `Payment` and `PaymentMethods` and field in `PaymentCrudController`

```
$this->crud->addField([
   'label'     => 'Payment Method',
   'type'      => 'select2',
   'name'      => 'payment_method_id',
   'entity'    => 'paymentMethod',
   'attribute' => 'name',
   'model'     => 'App\Models\PaymentMethod',
   'wrapperAttributes' => [
       'class' => 'form-group col-md-3',
   ],
]);
```

Relation in `Payment` model:

```
public function paymentMethod()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PaymentMethod::class, 'id', 'payment_method_id');
    }
```

Actually, this works as expected - I see all records from the `PaymentMethod` model in the options field. But I need to filter some values. I trying to modify model relation:

```
 public function paymentMethod()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(PaymentMethod::class, 'id', 'payment_method_id')->where('name', '!=', 'Online');
        }
```

But I still see all records in select options. How can I filter select values?

Comment: Isn't it hasOne relation? So for a Payment Model instance, there'll be only one paymentMethod right? . How exactly are you showing the options in the select options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting 'where' in relation make no sense, in my opinion, relation should be as it is, reflect tables 's relations ....

for your suituation you could use '[options](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#select2-1-n-relationship)' for 'select2' field:

```
  $this->crud->addField([
       'label'     => 'Payment Method',
       'type'      => 'select2',
       'name'      => 'payment_method_id',
       'entity'    => 'paymentMethod',
       'attribute' => 'name',
       'model'     => 'App\Models\PaymentMethod',
       'options' => (function ($query) {
        return $query->where('name', '!=', 'Online')->get();}),
       'wrapperAttributes' => [
           'class' => 'form-group col-md-3',
       ],
    ]);
```

something else ... for your [one to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many): it should be:

```
public function paymentMethod()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PaymentMethod::class,'payment_method_id');
    }
```

second parameter should be the foreign key ...

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!